Google Forms Issue - Responses
I have a Google Form for my techs on the road, in which they select their client's site and fill in their report.
My Form's question #1 is a Drop Down list of all my clients.
When I look at the Individual Responses in the Form itself, it shows ALL the client list with no indication of which client was selected when the Form was filed. The Excel Response file is okay, but visually harder to work with.
Anyone else having this issue?
Note : I have tried to change it to a 'check mark' instead of Dropdown list, and while all clients are still listed, the selected one is highlighted in the Response.


Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

This is a bug that showed up a few days ago.  A Google Community  Product Expert indicated a fix is expected soon.  Also on Reddit Dropdown questions stopped working... Since this is bug-related it is off-topic and will be closed.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug-related issue
